# Crear una lista de diccionarios a partir de varias listas

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, diccionarios, map

Tengo las siguientes listas:

```
pais = ['Argentina', 'Colombia'....]
capital = ['Buenos Aires', 'Bogota'...]
area = [1908, 1000,...]
poblacion = [50, 45,..]
```

Y necesito  crear una lista de diccionarios, y en cada diccionario debe aparecer la información del país, de tal manera que:

```
{'pais': 'Argentina', 'capital': 'Buenos Aires', 'area': 603700, 'poblacion': 51.8}.
```

He intentado iterar según el largo de la lista de `paises`... pero no me devuelve los valores que requiero:

```
for i in range(0,len(countries)):
    dict1['pais']=countries[i]
    dict1['capital']=capitals[i]
    dict1['area']=areas[i]
    dict1['poblacion']=populations[i] 

    list_dict.append(dict1)

for jugar in list_dict:
    print(jugar)
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionar esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo único que falta en tu código es que debes inicializar `dict1` en cada iteración del `for` ya que requieres un diccionario por cada país (cada iteración):

```
countries = ['Argentina', 'Colombia']
capitals = ['Buenos Aires', 'Bogota']
areas = [1908, 1000]
populations = [50, 45]

list_dict = []
for i in range(0, len(countries)):
    dict1 = {}
    dict1['pais'] = countries[i]
    dict1['capital'] = capitals[i]
    dict1['area'] = areas[i]
    dict1['poblacion'] = populations[i] 
    list_dict.append(dict1)

for jugar in list_dict:
    print(jugar)
```

No obstante, usar un range e indizado es considerablemente menos eficente y pitónico frente a un ciclo `for in` sobre el propio iterable. Hay una forma mucho más eficiente y simple de hacer esto usando `zip` y una lista por compresión:

```
countries = ['Argentina', 'Colombia']
capitals = ['Buenos Aires', 'Bogota']
areas = [1908, 1000]
populations = [50, 45]

list_dict = [
    {"pais": pais, "capital": cap, "area": area, "población": pop}
        for pais, cap, area, pop in zip(countries, capitals, areas, populations)
        ]

for jugar in list_dict:
    print(jugar)
```

`zip` toma los iterables que desees como argumento y genera otro iterable que en cada iteración retorna una tupla resultado de tomar el elemento iésimo de cada iterable pasado como argumento.

En este caso le pasamos las listas `countries, capitals, areas, populations`, en la primera iteración `zip` coge el primer item de `countries`, el primero de `capitals`, el primero de `areas` y el primero de `populations` y los reúne todos en una tupla (`('Argentina', 'Buenos Aires', 1908, 50)`) y la retorna. En la siguiente iteración coge el segundo item de cada lista, los reúne en una tupla y los retorna, y así sucesivamente hasta que al menos uno de los iterables no tiene más elementos.

```
for datos in zip(countries, capitals, areas, populations):
    print(datos)
```

> ```
> ('Argentina', 'Buenos Aires', 1908, 50)    
> ('Colombia', 'Bogota', 1000, 45)
> ```

Como zip nos retorna una tupla con cada iesimo item de cada lista, con

```
for pais, cap, area, pop in zip(...)
```

desempaquetamos la tupla, el primer item se asocia a `pais`, el segundo a `cap`, el tercero a `area` y el cuarto a `pop`, sería similar a :

```
for datos in zip(countries, capitals, areas, populations):
    pais = datos[0]
    cap = datos[1]
    area = datos[2]
    pop = datos[3]
```

Si te confunde la sintaxis de la lista por compresión, sería equivalente (aunque menos eficiente) que:

```
list_dict = []
for pais, cap, area, pop in zip(countries, capitals, areas, populations):
    list_dict.append({"pais": pais, "capital": cap, "area": area, "población": pop})
```

Comment: Gracias, fue de mucha ayuda, entiendo lo de poner dict1 al principio de cada for; ero no entiendo muy bien comando de zip, en realidad soy bastante principiante en esto.

Comment: Hola @SaraMendoza he editado la respuesta intentando explicar mejor que hace zip exactamente, si sigues sin entenderlo lo mejor es que crees un par de listas más largas y se pruebes con `for datos in zip(lista1, lista2): print(datos)` y observes que imprime en cada iteración.

Answer (score 1):

si corres el siguiente código:

```
pais=['Argentina', 'Colombia']
capital=['Buenos Aires','Bogota']
area=[1908,1000]
poblacion=[50,45]

list_dict = []

for i in range(len(pais)):
    dict1 = {}
    dict1['pais']=pais[i]
    dict1['capital']=capital[i]
    dict1['area']=area[i]
    dict1['poblacion']=poblacion[i] 
    list_dict.append(dict1)

print (list_dict)
```

Te devuelve esto: `[{'pais': 'Argentina', 'capital': 'Buenos Aires', 'area': 1908, 'poblacion': 50}, {'pais': 'Colombia', 'capital': 'Bogota', 'area': 1000, 'poblacion': 45}]`

¿Eso es lo que necesitabas?

Comment: Si, pero lo que me devuelve siempre es el elemento final, no hace iteración, repite un mismo elemento varias veces

Answer (score 0):

You could use list comprehesion:

```
[{'pais':pa, 'capital': ca, 'area': ar, 'pobalcion': po} for pa, ca, ar, po in zip(pais, capital, area, poblacion)]
```